# How to register a VB.Net User Control with jQuery

Tags: jquery, vb.net, user-controls

Greetings and thank you in advance for the help.  I created a user control in VB.NET that uses a jQuery datepicker.  I am at an impasse.  The code I have works for one datepicker control on the page but because I can only register the client script once, it will not work for multiple instances/datepickers on the same page.  What is the best way to go about initiating the jQuery script for this control so I can use it multiple times on one page? Can I append to ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript?  Thanks again.

```
Dim sJS As String = "$(function() { " & vbCrLf
sJS += " var dates = $('#" & txtDate1.UniqueID
sJS += "').datepicker({" & vbCrLf
sJS += " changeMonth: '" & _bMonthDropDown & "', changeYear: '" & _bMonthDropDown
sJS += "', numberOfMonths: '" & _numberOfMonths
...
sJS += "'}); });" & vbCrLf
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "DatePicker", sJS, True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make just a minor change to get the behavior you want.  Just change this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "DatePickerVars", sJS, True)
```

To have something unique for a key, like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "DatePickerVars" + txtDate1.UniqueID, sJS, True)
```

That key (combined with the type) is what determines if this script is already registered, which you'd want for example if you had 30 of a user control and only wanted to run a certain script once.  In this case though, you want **each** user control to register the script that's unique to it, so give it a key that won't be found as already being registered for this page.

Comment: Unfortunately, VS likes to insert this client-side javascript anywhere it wants in the document and not in the header which interfered with initialization.

Comment: Looking over the code I submitted, this is the best solution for what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS AJAX, you can always add this to the user control, which will ensure only one entry gets registered:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy id="asm" runat="server">
   <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/jquery.datepicker.min.js" />
   </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

And duplicates are ignored.  Or, you can have the user control let the page do the registration.  Lastly, you could add a property to the user control that says registerdatepicker, which when true, the user control uses the page.clientscript object to register the script.

Comment: At this time we need the code to work with IE6 without ActiveX AJAX isn't something we are ready to implement for this usercontrol. Thank you for the method though and I will refer back to this option once its deemed acceptable to celebrate the death of IE6 at our office.